# MSTest -> Why Can't I Debug Using BreakPoints?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, mstest

I setup breakpoints, then run "Run Tests" in Visual Studio. Why don't MSTest run to my breakpoints?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Choose `Debug` -> `Tests In Current Context` (or otherwise)

Answer (score 14):

For Visual Studio 2012 Express, I chose:

`TEST` -> `Debug` -> `All Tests`

Comment: Still valid for Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 1):

When using MSTest via `Start external program` "mstest" specify the `/noisolation` option.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after upgrading to [MSTest V2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/06/17/taking-the-mstest-framework-forward-with-mstest-v2).  I referenced the new nuget packages, removed the existing MSTest reference, but no debugging.  I [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file) that I should no longer be using a test settings file, so I removed that; no joy.  I finally discovered that clearing out my temp dir did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was that I had selected Release build. When I switched to Debug then my breakpoint was hit.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2022
with msTest, options:

1. When you are in test method press Ctrl + r, Ctrl + t to debug the current test method.
2. Go to menu test > debug last run
3. Go to menu Test > debug all test
4. Go to menu Test > Test Explorer, when the window test explorer open, right clic over the test method you want > Debug

the problem is that you "run" the test, but you must "debug" the test so you can make use of break points.

cheers.

Reference about [Testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/run-unit-tests-with-test-explorer?view=vs-2022) in visual studio